# need help modeling a flower(Chrysanthemum morifolium)

Tags: modeling, objects, hair, vertex-weights

so,I want to make a Chrysanthemum morifolium
specifically this type.
[image]

and the closest I can get to is this.
[image]

using hair emitter and vertex groups.
[image]

[image]

so, what should I do now?

Comment: can you provide blend file so we can try improve it?

Comment: One source could be [Erindale on flowers with Geometry Nodes](https://www.youtube.com/c/Erindale/search?query=flowers). It might take you a while to filter down to the right stuff, but it's good.

Comment: You could try shortening the hair length and scaling the model up?

Comment: I looked at the source and it will be really helpful for completing my project, thank you very much for such a useful source @RobinBetts

Comment: Update: use of geometry nodes and maths can help achieve the desired results in terms of flowers , do check it out, start with phyllotaxis.